# HTML to Note content

Tags: c#, api, evernote

When I trying to write some HTML text to Note, I have error (I think because HTML have some prohibited tags):

```
Evernote.EDAM.Error.EDAMUserException
```

When I use the same HTML with:

```
ENNote.Content = ENNoteContentAdvanced.NoteContentWithSanitizedHTML(HTML);
```

it works fine.

But I need get notes by ID, for updating. And I am not understand how I can write correctly HTML to Note (in HTML I have tables), or catching ENNote by GUID.

**UPD.**

I writing service for synchronization Notes (EN) between Evernotes and Microsoft Exchange Appointments (MA). When user create/update EN, my service create/update MA. When user update MA (created from Evernote), my service update EN. For linking I use EN GUID (I store it in MA in extended property). So I can find EN with this code:

```
List<ExtendedProperty> guids = appointment.ExtendedProperties.Where(ap => ap.PropertyDefinition == guidProp).ToList();

if (guids.Count > 0)
{
    string guid = (string)guids.First().Value;

    Note sNote = store.GetNote(guid, true, false, false, false);
}
```

But when I trying to set EN content I have error:
Error code "ENML_VALIDATION"
Parameter = "Document is invalid: no grammar found"

I can't store ENNoteRef in MA, because it object, not string. So I need to find ENNote by GUID (not ENNoteRef), or some stuff to set HTML to Note.Content without loosing tables.

Comment: what errors are you getting and why are you not able to read the elements by id once you send sanitized content to evernote

Comment: @Saravanan, error code "ENML_VALIDATION", Parameter = "Document is invalid: no grammar found". And nothing else. Read each DOM element and build ENML? This is a last pain, I think that it can work easily, because with ENNote I have no error. I trying to create new note from the same HTML and it work.

Answer (score 0):

It would help if you provide more of your code that surrounds the ENNote.Content call so we have more context.

Given the code you've provided: once you've created the ENNote and its content using the **NoteContentWithSanitizedHTML** function, you're then adding the note to the Evernote service with something like the following, correct?

```
ENNoteRef myNoteRef = ENSession.SharedSession.UploadNote(ENNote, null);
```

When you do this, you get back a NoteRef object, which is a reference to an actual specific note in the Evernote service. The NoteRef object has a **Guid** property, which is what you're looking for.

Comment: You said "I can't store ENNoteRef in MA, because it object, not string." That's right, but you can access and store ENNoteRef.Guid which is a string and is the unique identifier you're looking for.

Comment: look, I have GUID of note. When anybody changed MA, I get GUID, catch EN and... And ia have Note, note ENNote. And when I try to write MA.Body (is HTML) to EN.Content - I have error, that I described above.

Comment: OK, I think I understand your situation now. There may be a way you can use the Windows SDK to accomplish what you want. A question: are you storing these Evernote notes in a user's personal note store, business note store, or in a shared personal notebook(s)?